# OpenCV pixel access pointr vs. at() - Different values

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel, roi

I encountered weird behaviour when trying to access pixels as shown below:

```
void Dbscan::regionQuery(int i, int j, std::vector<Point>* res) const {
// check rect. grid around center point
const size_t row_min = std::max(0, i-eps_);
const size_t row_max = std::min(n_rows_, i+eps_+1);
const size_t col_min = std::max(0, j-eps_);
const size_t col_max = std::min(n_cols_, j+eps_+1);
assert(masked_img_.depth() == CV_8UC1);
for (int m = row_min; m<row_max; ++m) {
    const uchar* mask_ptr = masked_img_.ptr(m);
    for (int n = col_min; n<col_max; ++n) {
        assert(*mask_ptr == masked_img_.at<uchar>(m, n));
        if (masked_img_.at<uchar>(m, n) == 255) {
            res->emplace_back(Point(m,n));
        }
        mask_ptr++;
    }
}
```

Basically, the second assertion as shown fails and I'm rather clueless as to what is going on. Does anyone have an idea how to best approach debugging the problem above?

Bests regards

Felix

Comment: did you try `*(mask_ptr + n)` (without `mask_ptr++` at the end)?

Comment: does it work if you remove `mask_ptr++` and choose `assert(mask_ptr[n] == masked_img_.at<uchar>(m, n));` ?

Comment: @slawekwin Thanks, that worked! Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Isma The assertion fails, e.g. the accessed pixel values are different

Comment: @Micka Thanks, that also works. Can you imagine why incrementing the pointer would fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cv::Mat::ptr`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) returns a pointer to the beginning of the row from the argument, which is an address of an element in the first column of this row. [`cv::Mat::at`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) returns a reference to the element in the row and column from the argument. In your code the row matches, but the column doesn't (unless your `col_min` evaluates to 0), thus you need to move the pointer from `cv::Mat::ptr` `n` elements to match your column as well:

```
for (int m = row_min; m<row_max; ++m) {
    const uchar* mask_ptr = masked_img_.ptr(m);
    for (int n = col_min; n<col_max; ++n) {
        assert(*(mask_ptr + n) == masked_img_.at<uchar>(m, n));
        if (masked_img_.at<uchar>(m, n) == 255) {
            res->emplace_back(Point(m,n));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense!

Comment: but `mask_ptr++` should make sure that mask_ptr is always at the right col position, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Micka only as long as you start with the same element - `mask_ptr++` only guarantees that you move the pointer every iteration, but the initial offset is constant. You could keep the `mask_ptr++` (and skip the `+n` part) if you changed `mask_ptr` initialization to `masked_img_.ptr(m) + col_min`

Comment: yeah sorry, just saw the `col_min` myself. Thx.